# How can I split out a Slick interpolated query over multiple lines?

Tags: scala, slick

Is there any way to split a Slick interpolated query over multiple lines in your code? My queries tend to get rather long.

So I look for something like the following:

```
val query = sql"select * from DOCUMENTS " + 
            sql"where language = $lang order by publication_date desc"
query.as[ResearchDocument]
```

But this results in

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.slick.jdbc.SQLInterpolationResult[String]
 required: String
          sql"where language = $lang order by publication_date desc"
          ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, seems like the Scala triple quote string is the way to go:

```
val query = sql"""select * from DOCUMENTS
                  where language = $lang order by publication_date desc"""
```