# Issue with Spark-CSV sqlContext

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I invoke the following query in spark-shell.

```
sqlContext.sql("select cast(ts_time as varchar(10)),cast(y as varchar(10)),cast('0' as varchar(3)),case when x0 = '' then cast(null as float) else cast(x0 as float) end from tasmaxload UNION ALL
select cast(ts_time as varchar(10)),cast(y as varchar(10)),cast('1' as varchar(3)),case when x1 = '' then cast(null as float) else cast(x1 as float) end from tasmaxload").registerTempTable("testcast");
```

This throws error unclosed string literal in some of the places.

Then I managed to understand that, if query is given as follows in a single line, no errors and executes fine.

```
sqlContext.sql("select cast(ts_time as varchar(10)),cast(y as varchar(10)),cast('0' as varchar(3)),case when x0 = '' then cast(null as float) else cast(x0 as float) end from tasmaxload UNION ALL select cast(ts_time as varchar(10)),cast(y as varchar(10)),cast('1' as varchar(3)),case when x1 = '' then cast(null as float) else cast(x1 as float) end from tasmaxload").registerTempTable("testcast");
```

However is there a way I can manage this issue without making it a single line?

I ask this because the original query is broke up into more than 150+ lines and I can't keep changing it to single line all the time.

Can somebody help me out in this?

**FYI:** I also tried using the **:paste** mode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Sorry.

This question is [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091206/how-can-i-split-out-a-slick-interpolated-query-over-multiple-lines) in the forum.

The issue gets solved by changing the single double quotes to triple double quotes as follows,

```
sqlContext.sql("""select cast(ts_time as varchar(10)),cast(y as varchar(10)),cast('0' as varchar(3)),case when x0 = '' then cast(null as float) else cast(x0 as float) end from tasmaxload UNION ALL
select cast(ts_time as varchar(10)),cast(y as varchar(10)),cast('1' as varchar(3)),case when x1 = '' then cast(null as float) else cast(x1 as float) end from tasmaxload""").registerTempTable("testcast");
```

Hope this helps someone else too. Thank you.